# How to use Splitters in kivy with multiple screens?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, splitter

This is a simple example but essentially I need to use `Splitter` to separate and resize two individual Text input boxes horizontally, however when I'm trying to use the `Splitter` widget in a `Screen` its creating a double behind the original content and the `Splitter` is not functioning properly. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

**main file**

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager , Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.factory import Factory


class TestScreen1(Screen):
    pass
class TestScreen2(Screen):
    pass
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("D:\MainProject\TestFiles\my.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**KV file**

```py
Manager:
    TestScreen1:
    TestScreen2:


<TestScreen1>:
    name:"abc1"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            text:"Next"
        Splitter:
            sizable_from:"left"
            Button:
                text: "next"
                on_press: root.manager.current="abc2"

<TestScreen2>:
    name:"abc2"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            text:"pre"
        Splitter:
            sizable_from:"left"
            Button:
                text: "pre"
                on_press: root.manager.current="abc1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `kv` file is being loaded twice. Once by you `Builder.load_file()` and once by the `App` (see [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv)). Just remove that `Builder.load_file()` line.